# How can i add clickHandler to the <li> tag in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I want to add ClickHandler to the  < li> tag

please help me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a FocusWidget once you've got hold of the Element.  There's a FocusWidget constructor taking a single Element.  After that you can just call addClickHandler

Comment: can u please give me the example

Comment: FocusWidget w = new FocusWidget(liElement); w.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { ... });   should work.   Remember to add the Widget to your panel.  liElement is a freshly created LI-element.

Comment: But... FocusWidget is an abstract base class. It is not possible to instantiate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the `<li>` tag as a widget that implements the HasClickHandler interface. Then you can instantiate a ClickHandler and add it to the `<li>` widget.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm currently using. It works, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach.

```
public class ListItem extends HTMLPanel implements HasClickHandlers {
    public ListItem(String html) {
        super(html);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setElement(Element elem) {
        super.setElement(DOM.createElement("li"));
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
        return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
    }
}
```

This allows using UiBinder to define a ListItem which can then contain arbitrary HTML (and be clickable).